# unattended-upgrade: why no more unattended.progress file in 15.10?

Tags: apt, unattended-upgrades

I've written a little program in python to notify the installation of automatic upgrade in Ubuntu. It has worked since Ubuntu 13.10, but now with 15.10, it doesn't work any more.

Unattended-upgrade wrote a file named `/run/unattended-upgrades.progress`, or `/var/run/unattended-upgrades.progress`, with the percentage of the total installation of the upgrade.

My program read this file, but now the file is modified each day, but empty... I'm sad!

How can I fix it?

Comment: I think I understand your question, I was actually wondering why mine is stuck with `Progress: 97.2222 % (dpkg-exec)`. I'm on 16.04 and the file does not go away or show 100%. Rather useless in that intermediate state...

Comment: Yes, it was solved with an update. Today mine is `Progression : 98.2143 % (dpkg-exec)`. I had to modify my python script, all work now.